# How to lock a folder by password without echo?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to lock a folder using a built-in password, but without echo.

no (could be altered attrs), no "stamp" lockers, no echo because I don't need any .

If I try to access the folder which should be asking for a password now, or maybe a prompt message will ask for one, and I don't use the right one which was ( built-in ), then no access.

I need to specify the folder path, specify the password, save the batch and run it for the folder to be locked.

Comment: Where is the code you have written to perform the task laid out in your question. Without your code, we cannot help you to fix the specific issue you are having with it. This site does not offer a free coding to order service, if that was your intention, then I'd suggest you try some place else. Please take the [tour] and ensure you've read [ask] with all of its associated links, to learn how this site works and how to create a well formed on-topic question with a specific reproducible issue.

Comment: say ( RMDIR /S /Q "%windir%\temp\" ) for deleting a folder , which i want to lock by a password , a built-in one without echo .

Comment: You're going to have to be more descriptive, what do you mean by lock?  What is it echoing that you don't want to show?  In your Above Response, you mention DELETING a Folder, if you just want to suppress output from deleting a folder you pipe to NUL   `2>&1 >NUL` or `2>NUL 1>NUL`.   Using your Example this would be `( RMDIR /S /Q "%windir%\temp\" ) 2>NUL 1>NUL`

Comment: That's ok I think i'll ask another question , close this one for now :)) .